# How to save a collection of Postman requests to an existing Git repo?

Tags: git, postman

We've got an existing Api project that we are building which calls out to 3rd party Api's and aggregates datasets.

As part of testing and developing this we each have collections of Postman requests that we run locally to extract data from the 3rd parties for developing; calling a v1 of our Api to check we haven't broken it and for calling our new end points.

What we like to do is save the Postman collection of requests to the Api projects git repo. Then the next developer who branches can load the Postman collection from the repo, any edits they make are saved back to the repo, etc. etc.

This isn't as easy as it should be :-(

Comment: It doesn't look like postman saves collections to a commitable file. You'll likely need to export/import the collection when changes need to be shared

Answer (score 2):

Quote from blog post ***Better Practices for Git Version Control in Postman*** from Postman team

[image]

[image]

Your steps

- Create a workspace in Postman.
- Import or create an API specification in the workspace.
- Connect a “repository” with a Git hosting tool (e.g., GitHub or Bitbucket).
- “Commit” and save the changes to your workspace.
  ...

https://blog.postman.com/better-practices-for-git-version-control-in-postman/#how-git-works-in-postman

Read more

- Using version control https://learning.postman.com/docs/collaborating-in-postman/version-control/
- Versioning an API https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/versioning-an-api/versioning-an-api-overview/